# Is it possible to use websockets/long polling with an external api from third party provider?

Tags: node.js, websocket, long-polling

I have an application that gets data from multiple external apis. Now I would like to get real time data from these apis. Is it possible to use websockets and/or long polling in such a scenario where you do not have control over the apis/api responses yourself?

Basically I would like to listen to changes from these external apis and have my own server respond accordingly to those events.

Forgive me if this is a trivial question but I haven't used any of these techniques before and I'm not sure how these stuff usually work.

Comment: if this third party provider has in his code a port that waits for tcp sockets and update all the sockets that connected to him when ever a change is happening in there system. then yes you can do it pretty easily but this feature need to come from the  third party provider . you cant do it from the rest api

Comment: Ok. Thank you, that was what I needed to know. I will look into it!